# Override directory listing with MVC URL routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, asp.net-mvc-routing

Recently, I partially converted an Asp.Net web forms application to use MVC. We still have parts of the application in web forms (.aspx pages) and use MVC routing to work with Controllers and such.
I added an MVC route like

```
routes.MapRoute("Users", "Users/{controller}/{action}/", new { controller = "Timesheet", action = "List" });
```

There is a folder called "Users" which contain a few aspx pages we still use.
When I hit the URL `http://localhost/Users/` I get a directory listing of the contents of the "Users" folder. Apparently, the directory listing takes precedence over MVC url routing and this might be overridden by modifying the IIS7 server settings.

How could I override this behavior, via code or web.config changes?

References:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1251156.aspx/1

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/121/iis-7-and-above-modules-overview/

Comment: http://www.packtpub.com/article/mixing-asp.net-webforms-and-asp.net-mvc is the method I used to add MVC to an existing web forms application

Answer (score 2):

Setting RouteExistingFiles=true on the RouteCollection achieves just that. It will allow ASP.NET MVC to handle routes even for existing directories.

Comment: Hanselman has discussed this here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use this ignoreroute:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{WebPage}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
```

Listing the RegisterRoutes method

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");                         
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{WebPage}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");            

            //routes.MapPageRoute("users", "users", "~/admin/default.aspx");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "home", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }
```

This would exclude all pages whose extension is ".aspx" from routing.